# Bootstrap responsive embed not working inside flexbox - height is not being calculated - why?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

so I'm having an issue trying to use the Bootstrap reponsive embed classes inside a flexbox.

The classes work fine when things are stacked, but if I then use flexbox to place two divs side by side (one containing the video, the other a panel for text info), the video shifts to half width (which is correct) but the height remains the full height as if it were full width.

Nothing I seem to change is making the height stick to the ratio governed by the width changing from the flexbox.

Is this a bug in the responsive embed?

```
<div id="youtube-container">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'youtube', true); ?>"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="info"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: use bootstrap cols.

Comment: Erm... Nope, sorry don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

After a think, it dawned on me that the process BS uses to shift the aspect ratio is based on the parent container.

So after just entering a parent div around the responsive div, it works fine.

```
<div id="youtube-container">
    <div>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'youtube', true); ?>"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info"></div>
</div>
```